# How to store this Objective-C block inside a Swift variable?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

Here is the Objective-C block:

```objectivec
@property (copy) void (^anObjcBlock)();

anObjcBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Yea man this thing works!!");
};
NSMutableArray *theArrayThatHasTheBlockInItAtIndexZero = [NSMutableArray array];
[theArrayThatHasTheBlockInItAtIndexZero addObject:anObjBlock];
```

Here's what I did in Swift:

```swift
var theBlock: (()->Void)?

theBlock = theArrayThatHasTheBlockInItAtIndexZero[0] as? ()->Void
// Now call the block
theBlock!()
```

But with this I get runtime error.
Basically, the `theBlock = theArrayThatHasTheBlockInItAtIndexZero[0] as? ()->Void` statement would make `theBlock` nil because the `as?` failed. And when I changed the statement to `theBlock = theArrayThatHasTheBlockInItAtIndexZero[0] as! ()->Void`, I get a runtime error:

[image]

I'm not sure what else to do. This is an empty project, there really is no code in it.

Comment: Can you try to surround your block definition by bracket?
var theBlock: (()->Void)?

Comment: Yea sorry. I already had it bracketed. I edited the question

Comment: Ty to set the block type to `var block : (@convention(block) () -> Void)?`. (Swift 2.0 - for Swift 1.x use `@objc_block` instead of `@convention(block`)

Comment: @MatteoPacini this didnt work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Jai No, unfortunately. It's quite a weird error. I'll make more tests and come back.

Comment: @Jai Could you post the code where you're initialising the array, please?

Comment: Can you tell us what the runtime error was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the issue, in this case, comes from the **NSMutableArray**.

**[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]** returns **id** in Objective-C, which gets translated to **AnyObject** by Swift.

You will get an error if you attempt to cast **AnyObject** to **() ->Void**.

A workaround is the following:

```swift
// Create your own typealias (we need this for unsafeBitcast)
typealias MyType = @convention(block) () -> Void

// Get the Obj-C block as AnyObject
let objcBlock : AnyObject = array.firstObject! // or [0]

// Bitcast the AnyObject Objective-C block to a "Swifty" Objective-C block (@convention(block)) 
// and then assign the result to a variable of () -> Void type

let block : () -> Void = unsafeBitCast(objcBlock, MyType.self)

// Call the block
 
block()
```

This code works for me.

---

**FUNNY FACT**

If you edit your Objective-C code to look like this...

```objectivec
// Typedef your block type
typedef void (^MyType)();

// Declare your property as NSArray of type MyType
@property (strong) NSArray<MyType>* array;
```

Swift will now report the array type as **[MyType]!**.

For some reason, generics on **NSMutableArray** doesn't seem to be picked up by Swift.

Despite that, you'll get a runtime error if you execute:

```swift
let block : MyType? = array[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! To bad i cant upvote you twice. wow.. I'm looking into what your solution did exactly.

Comment: You need a type to use unsafeBitcast. Since you can't use `() -> Void` as a type, the trick is to create a typealias for it, so you can refer to it like in my code, using `.self`. Then you need to unsafeBitcast your block to the typealias type. Swift will then "remember" what the type of the block is, hence the objc block on the right gets converted to the Swift closure on the left. I hope this helps.